# Checkbox checklist attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I could not understand what this javascript line does.

```
chkBox.setAttribute("CheckList", range);
```

What is the "CheckList" attribute is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) attribute called "CheckList" for input elements.  Wherever that code is, it's setting a custom attribute on the element that it will likely access later.  Some people choose this in favour of creating a global variable, but really you should stick to expando properties (if you want to avoid global vars), for example:

```
chkBox.CheckList = range;
```

In Internet Explorers before version 8, *setAttribute* incorrectly maps to properties instead of attributes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find such attribute [on W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html), it looks like the programmers has tried to set a ***custom*** attribute eg:

```
<input type="checkbox" CheckList="something" />
```